# php create Array along with constant addition to value

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am looking to add up all the `$profit` with its associated array (`$mfgname`).

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
...
    $array[$mfgname] = $profittotal + $profit;
    echo $mfgname . " | " . $profit . "<br/>";
...
$i++; }
```

Spits out:

```
Mfgname1 | 5.00
Mfgname3 | 1.00
Mfgname1 | -1.00
Mfgname2 | 10.00
Mfgname3 | 4.50
Mfgname2 | -5.00
```

Profits are correct, however the array is only spitting out the last profit shown for the Mfg:

```
Array (
        [Mfgname1] => -1.00
        [Mfgname2] => -5.00
        [Mfgname3] => 4.50
      )
```

I am trying to add them up if it is associated with that Mfgname. I believe I have to find the array value in the while loop and try and add it to the newest output `$profit`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `$profittotal` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but here goes my guess

```
$array[$mfgname] += $profit;
```

Instead of

```
$array[$mfgname] = $profittotal + $profit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what it is you want, I think you are using the wrong variables in the wrong place.  Try this:

```
$profittotal = $array[$mfgname] + $profit;
echo $mfgname . " | " . $profittotal . "<br/>";
```